# Get the point coordinates of images of an interactive web map?

Tags: javascript, web-mapping, html, parse

I want to parse this web map for the point coordinates of the displayed icons:
https://www.mercedes-benz.de/passengercars/mercedes-benz-cars/dealer-locator.html

The HTML class of the items is "leaflet-marker-icon leaflet-zoom-animated leaflet-clickable"

Is there a way to find out the lat/lon-coordinates of every displayed item in the map?

I have not found any helpful workarounds.

Comment: Looks encrypted this is a response https://ajaxmap1.ptv.de/uams2/vectormaps/primarySource_deu/tok_fwff674g$$www.service-shop.mercedes-benz.com/tile/ts_2017011001/14/8505/5375

Comment: what are these locations? mercedes dealers? if you find the adress list for these locations you can geocode. Check it here https://www.shanelynn.ie/massive-geocoding-with-r-and-google-maps/

Comment: @Mapperz How could you get this response? Does that mean that I don´t have the rights to receive this data?  i want to get a list of all Dealers in Germany. I want to use this approach for other web maps as well, for example all Shell stations in Germany: http://www.shell.de/autofahrer/shell-station-locator.htm Thanks for your help!

Comment: Google Chrome>More Tools>Developer Tools> Network (reload the map) and trace the data sources. Looks like your out of luck scraping Mercedes-Benz as they have done a good job encrypting (as hey should). OpenStreetMap might be a better place to start https://tinyurl.com/merc-osm

Comment: Phil the Shell one is easy they have an export csv on their frontend go to http://locator.shell.co.uk/?country=DE&language=en_GB&site=rtl&modeselected=true&dist_units=km search Germany and export lat/lng is available with the rest of the attributes to map.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. It was quite difficult to find a way to read out icons, when there is no coordinate list at all. You can do this by the html pixel values. It is  difficult and it takes a lot of time for big areas, but it works.